# Trouble to download chatterbot library

Tags: python, error-handling, chatbot

I have 3.9 python and I want to download chatterbot library so I did 'pip install chatterbot' but I'm having this error. how can i fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5nCZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This error could be caused by several issues, if you don't need the newest version, the easiest thing to do is to install an older version. (Uninstall the previous version before downgrading)

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.4
```

If this isn't possible you could try reinstalling pip using,

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```